# Permutations summing to permutations

Tags: code-golf, permutations

Given an integer \$N\$ consider a permutation \$p=p_1,p_2,p_3,\ldots\$ of \$1,\ldots,N-1\$. Let \$P = p_1 , p_1+p_2 \bmod N, p_1+p_2+p_3 \bmod N, \ldots\$ be its prefix sums modulo \$N\$. Sometimes \$P\$ will be a permutation of \$1,\ldots,N-1\$ itself.

For example, \$N=4: p=3,2,1 \rightarrow P=3,1,2\$

Negative examples: \$p=2,3,1 \rightarrow P=2,1,2\$ is not a permutation ;
\$p=3,1,2 \rightarrow P=3,0,2\$ is a permutation but not of \$1,\ldots,3\$

Your task is to write a program or function that takes \$N\$ and returns the number of permutations \$p\$ of \$1,\ldots,N-1\$ such that \$P\$ is also a permutation of \$1,\ldots,N-1\$.

Rules:

You may return integers or integer-valued numbers.

You may return the \$N\$-th term, the first \$N\$ terms or the entire series.

You may ignore/skip odd \$N\$. If you choose to do so you may take \$N\$ or \$N/2\$ as the input.

Other than that default rules and loopholes for integer sequences apply.

This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins. Different languages compete independently.

First few terms:

\$
\begin{align}
2 &\rightarrow 1 \\
4 &\rightarrow 2 \\
6 &\rightarrow 4 \\
8 &\rightarrow 24 \\
10 &\rightarrow 288
\end{align}\$

[OEIS](http://oeis.org/A141599) has more.

Comment: OEIS says the problem is NP hard. I'd be willing to see a solution which isn't brute force

Comment: *Given an integer 1,…,N−1* doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you mean: *Given an integer N consider 1,…,N−1*. Also the next sentence talks about *p1*, *p2* etc without any definition  as what they represent.

Comment: @Noodle9 Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 60 bytes

```
Count[Sort/@Mod[Accumulate/@Permutations[r=Range@#-1],#],r]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcvBCsIwDADQXwkMPGXMeZ9U9CoMPYYcQu10YFOI6Un89rr7e1n8lbL4GqUtMLVzqep0L@ZDuJYHnWKsub7F0xDmZLn6Zot@yKab6DOFrh8ZO0bjXbsUmm3dvkJ/hIWUGeGrCAeEcf/j9gc)

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 24 bytes

```
1#.!(=&#[:=#|+/\)@A.&i.]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DZX1FDVs1ZSjrWyVa7T1YzQdHPXUMvVi/2typSZn5CukKWkrGCmYKJgpWPwHAA)

Straightforward brute force.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
ɽ:Ṗv¦⁰%vs^O
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvTrhuZZ2wqbigbAldnNeTyIsIiIsIjYiXQ==)

### How?

```
ɽ:Ṗv¦⁰%vs^O
ɽ           # exclusive range from 0; range(1, N)
 :          # duplicate top of stack
  Ṗ         # get permutations
   v¦       # vectorized cumulative sum
     ⁰      # push N to top of stack
      %     # modulo (vectorizes)
       vs   # vectorized sort
         ^  # flip stack (so range(1, N) is now on top)
          O # count number of instances
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 88 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,m=z=2**n-2,p=o=0,x,g=i=>(q=1<<++i)>m?o+=x==z:g(i,m&q&&f(n,m^q,i+=p,x|1<<i%n)))=>g``
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvRCoIwGIbh8@4j2e9@Q0eEhJ/dSSimY@E2zYgh3fuqw/D04X3v7atduoeZnpnztz7GAcKxxQqVpi5TPMEj58AaBrWYUVSVlIZqe/ESAVjPWhi2yZwkw@@8zmwkJg7vb2n2johQ66aJnXeLH/vD6LUYhCLa/ctxI6eNlBspcqL4AQ)

#### How?

We compute the bitmask \$z=2^n-2\$ where the bits \$1\$ to \$n-1\$ are set (e.g. \$n=4\$ gives \$z=14=1110_2\$).

We start with \$m=z\$ and \$x=0\$. We recursively clear the bits of \$m\$ in all possible orders while keeping track of the sum of said bit indices in \$p\$ and setting the bits \$p \bmod n\$ in \$x\$. (Note that we do not need to keep track of the permutation itself.)

We have a solution whenever we end up with \$x=z\$, in which case the output value \$o\$ is incremented.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
S#omȯOm%¹∫Ptŀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P1g5P/fEev9c1UM7H3WsDig52vD//38LAA)

```
           t   # tail: all except the first element of
            ŀ  # the sequence 0..N-1;
S#o            # now, how many times does this occur among
          P    #  get all permutations of this
   mȯ          #  and for each of them
         ∫     #   get the cumulative sums
      m%¹      #   each modulo the input
     O         #   and sort the results
```

---

**Alternative, also 13 bytes**

```
LSnm(†%¹∫)Pḣ←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9odXNr//9MU25tKOKAoCXCueKIqylQ4bij4oaQ////OA)

```
            ←  # decrement the input by 1
           ḣ   # get the sequence 1..N
          P    # and get all permutations of this;
 Sn            # now get all common elements between this and
   m(    )     #  for each permutation
        ∫      #   get the cumulative sums
     †%¹       #   each modulo the input
L              # how long is the resulting list of common elements?
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 23 bytes

```
{+/~^a?x!+\'a:?>'+!x#x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6rW1q+LS7SvUNSOUU+0srdT11asUK6o5eJKU1cwUjBRMAMAsswI8Q==)

`+!x#x` All length x combinations of `0 1 ... x-1`.
`a:?>'` The unique results of grading up each combination. This gives all permutation, assign these to `a:`.
`x!+\'` Cumulative sum of each permutation, modulo x.
`a?` Find each row in the result in the list of permutations. This gives nulls for non-permutations.
`+/~^` Count the non-null values.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’Œ!ðÄ%f⁸L
```

A monadic Link that accepts an integer and yields the count of permutations summing to permutations.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8yjkxQPbzjcopr2qHGHz////y0A)**

#### How?

```
’Œ!ðÄ%f⁸L - Link: integer, N
’         - decrement -> N-1
 Œ!       - all permutations of [1..N-1]
   ð      - start a new dyadic chain, f(permutations, N)
    Ä     - cumulative sums (of each of the permutations)
     %    - modulo N
      f⁸  - filter keep if in (the permutations)
        L - length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 71 bytes

```factor
[| n | n [1,b) <permutations> [ dup cum-sum [ n mod ] map ⊂ ] count ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU0xbgIxEOzvFdMiBQQoQhFEtCgNTZTqRGF8C7E4rx3vukAkDSXPzEcOW1CMNDM7M3swVkMavj4/tpsl@mBNL/BGvyfJ8JGe3Aa/d2xK0lnBiRJT/7iIGnWi1a4aQj@Z2JaikApiItVzTI71kc/sbOgIq6a5YI5XLPCG2RR/zdD@glHRzl72I7xHSj7X@cCyRosuR9jsx5J9UQwfOuzKasT/7VqYDbl82Q3VmQx3)

- `n [1,b) <permutations>` Get all the permutations of [1..n) as a virtual sequence.
- `[ ... ] count` Count how many of them...
- `dup cum-sum [ n mod ] map ⊂` ...are supersets of their cumulative sum modulo n.

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 30 bytes

```
J-.ror@Jbcjm{q++pa}x/.%q~[Z]++
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V9daFBcXpT530tXryi/yMErKTkrt7pQW7sgsbZCX0@1sC46KlZb@39teM5/IwVDLhMFIy4zBRMuCwUjEy4A)

```
J      # Dup
-.     # Decrement
ro     # Range 1..N-1
r@     # Permutations
J      # Dup
bc     # Infinite cycle
j      # Swap
m{     # Map
 q++   # Sum
 pa    # Partial
}
x/     # Reorder stack
.%     # Modulo
q~[Z]  # Zip with contained in permutations
++     # Sum (count)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
L¨œεηOI%{āQ}O
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59CKo5NPTTq33d9TtfpIY2Bt@v//FgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9vc2FiaWX/VMOFw4jCpnZ5PyIg4oaSICI/ecKp/0zCqMWTypLOt0/CriV7xIFRfWf/LP8).

**Explanation:**

```python
L           # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 ¨          # Remove the last item to make the range [1,input)
  œ         # Get all its permutations
   ʒ        # Filter the permutations by:
    η       #  Get all prefixes of the current permutation
     O      #  Sum each prefix
      I%    #  Modulo the input
        {   #  Sort it
         ā  #  Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping)
          Q #  Check if both lists are the same
   }g       # After the filter: pop and push the length
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 116 bytes

```
from itertools import*
f=lambda n:(r:=set(range(1,n)))and sum({sum(x[:i])%n for i in r}==r for x in permutations(r))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY5BCsIwEEX3nmJAhETiQhEpgZykdBFpooFmEiZTqIgncdON3snbaMX6Fx8ePPj__swXPiccx0fPflO92FOKENgRp9QVCDEn4vXCm87GY2sBtSBtimNBFk9ObBVKKS22UPoorlMNtQ6NXCH4RBAgINDNGPriMGF2FHu2HBIWQVL-tpd_od6pvTqoqtEL-CRTQBZeDLM6330D)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 102 bytes

```
import Data.List
f n=length$filter((`elem`p).tail.map(`mod`n).scanl(+)0)p where p=permutations[1..n-1]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=Nc2xDQIxDADAnilSUCRCb_EdzXeUbICQYoFDIhwnSvxiGJpvEDOxDQVwC9zjFbHfiHlZnrOGYfcOKdfS1OxREQ6p6yoYmZjkqnEdEis1az0xZV8dKCaGjNX6XC5eHPQzCtuN27pq7pEamTpVanlW1FSkH0cAGcbTd_ul__wD)